# Qt keep scrollbar enabled in disabled table

Tags: qt, scrollbar

I'm using tablemodel with vertical scrollbar and want to keep the scrollbar always enabled no matter what status the table is.

Perhaps its possible to disable all flags for table or docking the scrollbar on the right side of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `QAbstractTableModel`, you can reimpliment the [`flags()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#flags) member function to return a read-only flag.

Have a look at the [Qt::ItemFlags](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum) to see which ones you need and then leave off what you don't. At the very least, you should **not** be returning `Qt::ItemIsEditable`

Answer (score 1):

We had this issue with QScrollArea and solved it manually (eventually subclass and reimplement setEnabled).

```
area->setDisabled(false);
foreach(QWidget *w, area->findchildren<QWidget*>())
{
    w->setDisabled(true);
}
```